# Removing Double Quotes from String type data while writing CSV using SPARK

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

We are using Java with Spark . Current Requirement is to write a Dataset to Spark , with Space as Delimeter. Below is the code which I have tried:

```
 fooDataSetObject.coalesce(1).map((MapFunction<FooDataSet, FooDataSet>) fooDataSet -> 
 FileOperations.call(fooDataSet,broadcastedProperty),encoder).select("column","cons_zero",
            "columnA","columnB","columnC","columnD",
            "constants_value")
            .write()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", true)
            .option(Constants.DELIMITER, " ")
            .option(Constants.IGNORE_LEADING_WHITESPACE, ApplicationConstants.FALSE)
            .option(Constants.IGNORE_TRAILING_WHITESPACE, ApplicationConstants.FALSE)
            .option("quote", " ")
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save(path);
```

I have used QuoteMode as None but didn't work.
When I tried using Quote Option with Value as "\u0000" it adding special characters to the file.
I also tried using Quote Option with Explicitly applying the UTF-8 Encoding Option.

Is there anything else that needs to be done from the Configuration side of Java or SPARK. I have tried using --conf as a parameter while submitting spark job and giving encoder as UTF-8.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Sample DataSet values:

```
|  00123400|   93115212345678|     16|       0C|Tickets Cash-back |                57695857|           602140|                24394483|                          24394483|        0|                  99|60214057695857Tic...|66754325-83d1-426...|          24|                null|   01|c28380c5-c926-4b4...|Identity Defence  |Let's Go...Rewards|             null|     null|         ON|    17|          12345678|GB 29 NWBK 12345 ...|         931152|            null|cb032911-4c4e-406...|                     null|            20987|ABC...|                 GBR|                962000|             cashback|null|X Batch        |                null|                    99|12345             |
|  00123400|   93115212345678|     17|       0C|Tickets Cash-back |                57695857|           602140|                24394483|                          24394483|        0|                  99|60214057695857Tic...|23703242-e130-48b...|          24|                null|   01|a4e52b47-8866-4d1...|Identity Defence  |Let's Go...Rewards|             null|     null|         ON|    17|          12345678|GB 29 NWBK 12345 ...|         931152|            null|ee98f2e8-f489-4f3...|                     null|            20987|ABC...|                 GBR|                962000|             cashback|null|X Batch        |                null|                    99|12345             |
|  00123400|   93115212345678|     19|       0C|Tickets Cash-back |                57695857|           602140|                24394483|                          24394483|        0|                  99|60214057695857Tic...|c7138601-b26d-49d...|          24|                null|   01|dfefcf96-4f56-4ab...|Identity Defence  |Let's Go...Rewards|             null|     null|         ON|    17|          12345678|GB 29 NWBK 12345 ...|         931152|            null|dd9027bd-4fcd-45d...|                     null|            20987|ABC...|                 GBR|                962000|             cashback|null|X Batch        |                null|                    99|12345             |
|  00123400|   93115212345678|     20|       0C|Tickets Cash-back |                57695857|           602140|                24394483|                          24394483|        0|                  99|60214057695857Tic...|63cbd563-2af4-472...|          24|                null|   01|9629f346-7dde-429...|Identity Defence  |Let's Go...Rewards|             null|     null|         ON|    17|          12345678|GB 29 NWBK 12345 ...|         931152|            null|7b9d0698-0de1-45d...|                     null|            20987|ABC...|                 GBR|                962000|             cashback|null|X Batch        |                null|                    99|12345             |
```

Output:

```
93115212345678 0 "GB 29 NWBK 12345 78978911     " 00123400 "12345             " 99 "60214057695857Tickets Cash-back 0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```
.option("quote", "\"")
.option("escape", "\"")
```

For more information please see [CSV Data Source for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

Comment: Same Result:
93115212345678 0 "GB 29 NWBK 12345 78978911     " 00123400 "12345             " 99 "60214057695857Tickets 0"

Still quotes are present.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data for one row with quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Went through following documentation.

1. quote (default "): sets a single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. If you would like to turn off quotations, you need to set not null but an empty string. This behaviour is different from com.databricks.spark.csv.
2. escape (default ): sets a single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value.

Now even If I have changed code to using SEP instead of DELIMETER it was giving the same issue, because Spark was adding \u0000 which represents a NULL character. 
Tried givng an empty string reslts were same.

So I have shifted to using a Spark Text format and I m using a Java formatter in backgroud to create my comma seperated row.